# How to move an element in a matrix r to one of its adjacent cell (without knowing the element's location in the grid in advance)?

Tags: matrix, random

I created a 10 x 10 matrix which was originally filled up with empty spaces. Then I placed 25 characters 'a' in random cells on the grid. Now I need to move each one of them to one of the two to four adjacent cells (consider the 'a' next to the edge or in the corner). If the chosen destination was occupied by another 'a', it should stay where it is.

Here is my approach to the problem (the code itself looks lengthy now)

1. break the 10✕10 grid into 9 possible situations (in the middle 8✕8, four corners and four edges of the grid)
2. for each of case above, I check each one of the two to four adjacent cells. If it containes an empty space, I swap 'a' with it.

However, this results in a huge ugly piece of code. So, I wanted to ask: (1)is there a way that I can do the boundary check without breaking the grid into 8 different situations? (2) How can I choose the destination for each of the 25 'a' RANDOMLY?

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: You aren't talking about vectors at all (in the sense that the tags mean the term). Instead, you are talking about a *matrix* of positions. The fact that you are representing that matrix as a vector of vectors is an implementation detail which depends on programming language -- something that you didn't specify. Why not post your code and add the appropriate language tag?

Comment: Also, your description of what you are trying to do seems both inconsistent and underspecified. In the first paragraph you say that you first pick a direction and then stay put if the chosen direction is occupied. But in your point 2, you describe a seemingly deterministic search for a free cell and then take the first free cell (if any). Which is it? Do you choose a move randomly and then check if the move is possible or do you first look for possible moves? If the former, how do you decide what to do when two things try to move into the same unoccupied space?